# How to return different scopes for different roles in IdentityServer 4?

Tags: c#, .net-core, identityserver4

I am using IdentityServer4 for protecting my .net core app. I would like to use [Policy-Based Authorization](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt826337.aspx)

Here is example of one policy I did

```
 options.AddPolicy("api.order.write", builder =>
                builder.RequireScope(
                    "app.write", "app.read", "app.order.read"));
```

I would like to grant different scopes for different roles. For example user with role Viewer will have only app.read scope. So during login request web client send request to identity with list of all scopes we have in app, but than it should handle and return token with role based scopes. I think I can implement custom `IProfileService` and check user roles there and add claim with scopes, but maybe there is already solution for this. Do you have any ideas ?

UPD:  I created custom `IProfileService` and I am checking user role and than set specific list of scopes like this

```
                //removing existing scopes if such exist already 
                context.IssuedClaims = context.IssuedClaims.Where(x => x.Type != "scope").ToList();

                foreach (var scope in viewerScopes)
                {
                    context.IssuedClaims.Add(new Claim("scope", scope));
                }
```

but I still receive all scopes (not per role), the same list of scoped which web client sends during login request.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're mixing client authorization (i.e. scopes in OAuth/OIDC parlance) and user authorization here.

The user authorization checks should take place inside the API/resource itself (and *after* the basic scope check has occurred) and not in the IDS4 service at the point of issuing tokens.

https://leastprivilege.com/2016/12/16/identity-vs-permissions/

Comment: but token contains scopes and they can not be the same for all the users @mackie

Comment: am I right @mackie ?  Because it doesnt make sense to keep scopes if you have only web client.

Comment: Scopes can and should be the same for all users of a given client. Scopes control what a *client* can access and *not* what a user can access. The "auth" in OAuth is the resource owner (user) granting the client (the app) access to their resources (scopes). User authorisation is a separate thing entirely and should be handled within the resource/API.

Comment: after a bit bigger research I agree with you @mackie . Scopes should be  used to secure api for different clients. Marking you answer as correct. Thanks